# Como mesclar linhas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Como posso mesclar duas ou mais `**Linhas x Coluna**` da consulta abaixo?

```
select cast(OS.CreateDate as date) as DtMovimentacao, OS.Id as NrOS, OS.Description Origem, OSI.Description as ItemSaida, OSI.Quantity as QtdSaida,
OSE.Description, OSE.Quantity, OSE.Notes
from Asset_WorkOrders OS
join Asset_WorkOrderOtherCost OSI
on OSI.WorkOrderId = OS.Id
join 
(
    select OS.WorkOrderId, OSI.Description,OSI.Quantity,OSI.Notes from Asset_WorkOrders OS
    join Asset_WorkOrderOtherCost OSI
    on OSI.WorkOrderId = OS.Id
    where TypeId = 56
)OSE
on OSE.WorkOrderId = OS.Id
where OS.Id = 147412
and OS.TypeId = 34
```

Precisava que o resultado ficasse assim.
[image]

Isso na `query` ou através do `Report Server`.

Comment: Você quer que uma linha tenha N informações de ItemSaida e QtdSaida?

Comment: Exatamente, algo que limpe o campo caso ele seja idêntico os outros deixando apenas um...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Com SQL acho que a única forma é verificar as informações que são diferentes entre as linhas e usar o `FOR XML PATH` naquela coluna, no exemplo a seguir usei na coluna "Description"

```
select cast(OS.CreateDate as date) AS DtMovimentacao, OS.Id AS NrOS,
Origem = (SELECT OS2.Description + CHAR(10)
FROM Asset_WorkOrders OS2
WHERE OS.Id = OS2.Id
  and OS.TypeId = OS2.TypeId
FOR XML PATH(''))
OS.Description as Origem,

OSI.Description as ItemSaida, OSI.Quantity as QtdSaida,
OSE.Description, OSE.Quantity, OSE.Notes
from Asset_WorkOrders OS
join Asset_WorkOrderOtherCost OSI
on OSI.WorkOrderId = OS.Id
join 
(
    select OS.WorkOrderId, OSI.Description,OSI.Quantity,OSI.Notes from Asset_WorkOrders OS
    join Asset_WorkOrderOtherCost OSI
    on OSI.WorkOrderId = OS.Id
    where TypeId = 56
)OSE
on OSE.WorkOrderId = OS.Id
where OS.Id = 147412
and OS.TypeId = 34
```

Como você não incluiu informações das tabelas, pode ter algum inconsistência no resultado da coluna Origem, neste caso tem incluir na subquery alguns `JOINs` ou validações no `WHERE`.

Comment: Mas assim ainda iria trazer a informação nas duas linhas só que agora agrupada em uma coluna só

Comment: Também não é isso né ? você quer que o resultado da query Mescle colunas na planilha do Excel ?

Comment: Não na planilha do `Excel`, mas da forma que o `Excel` faz, isso na `query` ou no report server.

Comment: Com o XML PATH você incluir uma quebra de linha CHR(10) após cada palavra, mesmo assim a linha seria uma só, mas na coluna que usar esta função os dados estariam um em baixo do outro, acho que a melhor solução pode estar no Report Server, não sei usa-lo.