# Como mesclar Celula no Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, relatório, reporting-services

*Olá Pessoal,*

*Preciso de um help com uma situação no Reporting Services.*

*Preciso mesclar células em dados no Reporting Services como mostra a imagem abaixo, ou seja na **imagem 1** é o meu cenário atual e na **imagem 2** é o cenário que eu preciso deixar. **"Tratei os dados no Excel para facilitar o entendimento."**
Alguém tem alguma dica?*
*As informações do Plano de Venda estão dentro de um **"Tablix"** que está dentro de uma **"célula"** esta célula está no grupo de linhas do **"Tablix"** principal do meu relatório. os dados estão sendo listados a partir de uma **"procedure"**.*

*Preciso também que o cabeçalho seja exibido uma unica vez.*

[image: Imagem Cenários]

*Grato.*

Comment: Isso não tem como fazer

Comment: _Obrigado por sua resposta._

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102034/sql-server-mesclar-linhas

Comment: Eu já consegui fazer isso em uma ocasião, infelizmente não lembro como resolvi a questão, mas tenho quase certeza que foi com recursos de agrupamento, inclusive tinha colocado o botão "+" para expandir as seleções.